# How can I create a SUM of one column within a query in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have one table with multiple columns.  I am needing to create an SQL query to display certain columns based off of the user input from a datepicker and a select box.  I have done that just fine. However, I am needing one of the result columns to be totaled at the bottom of the display table. I cannot figure out how to create a result within my current query to display the totaled column. Essentially, I would like the WTTotal column to be totaled into a separate cell. My current query is below. I really think this is something simple that I just can't seem to see.

```
SELECT REPLACE(Client,',',' ') AS Client,WorkTicketNum,Lease,Date,OrderedBy,WTTotal 
FROM WorkTicket 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' AND Invoiced IS NULL 
ORDER BY Client
```

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: You want a column for *every* row that shows the total sum? That's...weird. Are you using a database that supports common table expressions?

Comment: No I am not wanting a column for every row. Essentially I just want the last row in the WTTotal column to be a SUM. I am using SQL Server 2014 and PHP, for those that want that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(Client,',',' ') AS Client,WorkTicketNum,Lease,Date,OrderedBy,WTTotal 
FROM WorkTicket 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' AND Invoiced IS NULL 
ORDER BY Client 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(WTTotal)
FROM WorkTicket
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' AND Invoiced IS NULL;
```

Comment: I tried using this but received the following error:
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'."

Comment: @K3n5: SQL Server does not allow this, unfortunately.  It requires the `ORDER BY` to apply to the whole query, rather than the individual subqueries, which means the grand total row will not be the last row.  If anyone knows a way around this, feel free to fix the answer.  In the mean time, OP should probably use a client-side solution like Marc B's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have it with a single query. Putting a `SUM()` into your query would require a `GROUP BY` clause and collapse all of your original result rows down into a single result row - meaning your table would disappear. What you want a is a client-side solution. e.g. Start a counter in your client code and manually add up the results. In pseudoish-code:

```
$sum = 0;
while( $row = fetch_from_db() ) {
   $sum += $row['field_to_sum'];
   display_row();
}
echo "Total: $sum";
```

Comment: It can be done, but as per the other answers it's very awkward. Unless the datasets are ginormous, you're better off doing the sum in the application.

Comment: indeed. the union would work, but it's essentially now THREE queries. the overall query plus the two subqueries comprising the union.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it in a separate column, not in a separate row, either you calculate it in a subquery and join it to your result:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Client,',',' ') AS Client,WorkTicketNum,Lease,Date,OrderedBy, my_calculated_sum AS WTTotal 
FROM WorkTicket
JOIN (SELECT SUM(whatever_you_want_to_sum) as my_calculated_sum FROM WorkTicket) subquery_alias
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' AND Invoiced IS NULL 
ORDER BY Client
```

Or you just calculate it with variables, like a running total. Your result is in the last row of the column.

```
SELECT REPLACE(Client,',',' ') AS Client,WorkTicketNum,Lease,Date,OrderedBy, @sum_variable := @sum_variable + whatever_you_want_to_sum AS WTTotal 
FROM WorkTicket 
, (SELECT @sum_variable := 0) var_init_subquery
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' AND Invoiced IS NULL 
ORDER BY Client
```

But actually Kevin's solution is very good.

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar solution as Kevin's :

```
;with cte_result
as 
(
    SELECT REPLACE(Client,',',' ') AS Client,WorkTicketNum,Lease,Date,OrderedBy,WTTotal 
    FROM   WorkTicket 
    WHERE  Date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-31' AND Invoiced IS NULL 
)
select * 
from   cte_result
union
select 'TotalAmount',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,sum(WTTotal)
from   cte_result
order  by client
```

but this solution will work only if your DB Engine supports CTE.
with a CTE, we can use same resultset to get total's row.